# How to access enabled property of elements present inside a list row in appmaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a list in which the listRow contains a panel inside. Then, inside the panel there are 3 text fields. I want to disable those 3 text fields through code but the problem is that I am not able to access the enabled property of those 3 text fields.

I tried the following to no avail:

```
var x=app.currentPage.descendants.FileList.descendants._values;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [List Widget](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#List) documentation, the properties table explains:

> **descendants** - All the children of this Layout widget recursively, identified by their names. This excludes any repeated children, such as rows in a List, cells in a Grid, Accordion, and their content.

Therefore, using descendants will definitely NOT give you what you want. Moreover, it also explains:

> **children** - The direct children of this Layout widget, identified by their names.

Here, is not specifying that it will exclude repeated children, and since each row item in a list is a repeated child, then this is the option we need to use.

Now, invoking the children will give us a [PropertyMap](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#PropertyMap), so we need to iterate through each item by invoking the PropertyMap values. So you need to do this:

```
var rows = app.currentPage.descendants.FileList.children._values;
rows.forEach(function(row){
    var rPanel = row.descendants.[PanelWidgetName];
    var panelDescs = rPanel.descendants.
    panelDescs.forEach(function(desc){
        desc.enabled = true; //false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following code:

```
var listRow = app.currentPage.descendants.FileList.children._values;
for (var i in listRow) {
  var inputs = listRow[i].YourPanelName.children._values;
  for (var j in inputs) {
    inputs[j].enabled = false;
  }
}
```

Basically, you first have to access the List widget children, which are the list rows, then for each list row you can reference the panel within each row just by calling the name of the panel and then calling the children inside that panel which are your inputs. That is why this requires a nested loop. I did not test this, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and simple explanation.